# Using a set variable inside the LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I'm trying to select the top 50% from a row. The way I'm doing it is by first calculating how many elememts there are in the row, dividing by 2, then using that result inside the LIMIT clause.

```
SET @UPPER := (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(LONG_W)/2) FROM STATION);
SELECT LONG_W FROM STATION ORDER BY LONG_W DESC LIMIT @UPPER;
```

I'm doing it in the Hackerrank website, and I do have selected the MySQL dialect.

If I do `Select @UPPER;` I am getting the expected result, 250 in this case. If I simply write `LIMIT 250` it does work, but I'm trying to do it with the variable since I can't always expect to know what is the exact middle.

Currently getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@UPPER' at line 1.

I've check to make sure the variable holds the right value and I've manually used that value to check if I get the expected result.

Comment: Always start by referring to the official documentation. Even if you get an expert answer, you should still always check the official documentation concurs. So, just start there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variables within the LIMIT clause. As per [MySQL official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

As suggested by the doc, you can only achieve this using a prepared statement (with a dynamic query) or a stored program.

```
SET @UPPER := (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(LONG_W)/2) 
               FROM STATION);

SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT LONG_W 
                    FROM STATION 
                    ORDER BY LONG_W DESC 
                    LIMIT ', @UPPER);
                   
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s34jQp3CT9WwS4DUeVMYCu/2).

---

Dynamic querying is prone to SQL injection. If you feel this may be a relevant problem to your use case, you can execute your dynamic query within a stored procedure, to enforce strong typization of inputs.

```
SET @UPPER := (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(LONG_W)/2) FROM STATION);

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE generate_sample_stations(
    IN num_stations INT
)
BEGIN
    SET @num_stations = num_stations;

    PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT LONG_W 
                       FROM STATION 
                       ORDER BY LONG_W DESC 
                       LIMIT ?';
    
    EXECUTE stmt USING @num_stations;
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL generate_sample_stations(@UPPER);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s34jQp3CT9WwS4DUeVMYCu/1).

Note: If you can avoid using variables for your `LIMIT` clause at all, it's better in the far end.